# Sequelize giving 500 error while trying to insert foreign key

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a join table `ManufacturerTab`. When I try to insert foreign keys value `manufacturerId: 1` and `tabsTemplateId: 1`, I'm getting 500 error:

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 267,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "23502",
        "detail": "Failing row contains (24, 2018-12-04 14:46:43.183+00, 2018-12-04 14:46:43.183+00, null, null).",
        "schema": "public",
        "table": "ManufacturerTabs",
        "column": "manufacturerId",
        "file": "execMain.c",
        "line": "2008",
        "routine": "ExecConstraints",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"ManufacturerTabs\" (\"id\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'2018-12-04 14:46:43.183 +00:00','2018-12-04 14:46:43.183 +00:00') RETURNING *;"
    },
    "original": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 267,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "23502",
        "detail": "Failing row contains (24, 2018-12-04 14:46:43.183+00, 2018-12-04 14:46:43.183+00, null, null).",
        "schema": "public",
        "table": "ManufacturerTabs",
        "column": "manufacturerId",
        "file": "execMain.c",
        "line": "2008",
        "routine": "ExecConstraints",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"ManufacturerTabs\" (\"id\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'2018-12-04 14:46:43.183 +00:00','2018-12-04 14:46:43.183 +00:00') RETURNING *;"
    },
    "sql": "INSERT INTO \"ManufacturerTabs\" (\"id\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'2018-12-04 14:46:43.183 +00:00','2018-12-04 14:46:43.183 +00:00') RETURNING *;"
}
```

**POST REQUEST:**

```
http://localhost:3000/manufacturers/1/manufacturer-tabs
```

**BODY JSON:**

```
{
    "manufacturerId": 1,
    "tabsTemplateId": 1
}
```

**Route**

```
/* Add Manufacturer Tab */
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    models.ManufacturerTab.create({
      manufacturerId: req.body.manufacturerId,
      tabsTemplateId: req.body.tabsTemplateId
    }).then(function(manufacturer_tab) {   
    res.status(200).json(manufacturer_tab);  
  }, function(error) {  
    res.status(500).send(error);  
  });  
});
```

Comment: \`"sql": "INSERT INTO \"ManufacturerTabs\" (\"id\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\")...` Executed SQL is only taking `id`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` columns. `manufacturerId` and `tabsTemplateId` are defined in your model?

Comment: You're correct... `manufacturerId` and `tabsTemplateId` were not defined in the model leading to this error.

Comment: glad it helped :)